# Design all 'pre' tags inside a div in css

Tags: css, tags, pre

How do i style the width of all "pre" tags inside a div with some id ? I can't put the "class" attribute inside the pre tag, becouse the pre tag is written by a function that i have no access to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS

```
#parent {} /* add style to the parent element */
#parent pre {color: red} /* to the pre */
```

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
  <pre>aaa</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

like this???

```
div#id pre { styles here }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this selector `div#someId pre`...............

```
div#someId pre
{
    width: ...
}
```